# SqlDataSource run stored procedure twice

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

I have the following table

```
[Department]  [Location]    [Project]      [Job Title]   [Qty]
-------------------------------------------------------------  
HR            Jeddah        Andalusia       JT2            5  
IT            Jeddah        Head Office     JT1            3
```

and I'm trying to run a sorted procedure using SqlDataSource as the following

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MManPowerUpdate]
    @Dept     nvarchar(350),
    @Loca     nvarchar(350),
    @Proj     nvarchar(350),
    @JobT     nvarchar(350)
AS

   IF (SELECT QTY FROM [MANPOWER] WHERE ([Department] = @Dept) AND ([Location] = @Loca) AND ([Project] = @Proj) AND ([JobTitle] = @JobT)) > 0
       Begin
         SELECT  'Operation Completed Successfully.' AS [Result]
         UPDATE [MANPOWER] SET QTY = QTY - 1 WHERE ([Department] = @Dept) AND ([Location] = @Loca) AND ([Project] = @Proj) AND ([JobTitle] = @JobT)
       End
   Else
       Begin
         SELECT 'Can''t Execute Operation.' AS [Result]
       End
Return 0
```

ASP.net Code :

```
  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:_JOOBERConnectionString %>" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" SelectCommand="MManPowerUpdate">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtDept" Name="Dept" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtLoca" Name="Loca" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtProj" Name="Proj" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtJobT" Name="JobT" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Result" HeaderText="Result" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Result" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

vb.net code behind :

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    SqlDataSource1.Select(New DataSourceSelectArguments)
End Sub
```

When I execute the code with this values ex.

```
@Dept  = HR
@Loca  = Jeddah
@proj  = Andalus
@JobT  = JT2
```

I expect the Qty to be 4 after update and retrieve 'Operation Completed Successfully.' but I used to get 3 after update, and that's mean the update statement was run twice when i called the procedure.
so I hope to find the solution with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your Select query also updates your data. Since the Select query is [automatically called](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.select(v=vs.110).aspx) on `PreRender` during life cycle, the decrement operation is done twice when clicking on the button: once in your button click event handler and once in `PreRender` (and it probably decrements `QTY` each time you open your form, even if you don't press `Button1`).

One solution would be to define `MManPowerUpdate` as the Update query:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:_JOOBERConnectionString %>" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" UpdateCommand="MManPowerUpdate">
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtDept" Name="Dept" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtLoca" Name="Loca" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtProj" Name="Proj" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtJobT" Name="JobT" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And call it when you click the button:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    SqlDataSource1.Update()
    GridView1.DataBind()
End Sub
```

You could define another Select query, which would get the data and show it the GridView, without modifying it.